# Rapidminer generate report not showing the generated graph

Tags: reporting, rapidminer

I have a simple rapid miner process in which I apply decision tree operator to my data set & try to generate a report with the generated decision tree graph. I can see the graph generated in the results tab, but it's not included in the generated report.

Can anyone please point out on what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="6.5.002">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>


 <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/>
    <parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/>
    <parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/>
    <parameter key="notification_email" value=""/>
    <parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/>
    <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_excel" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read Excel" width="90" x="45" y="30">
        <parameter key="excel_file" value="C:\Users\RoshanaSheri\Dropbox\RoshanaSheri\Practical-3\p3 datasets\churn.xls"/>
        <parameter key="sheet_number" value="1"/>
        <parameter key="imported_cell_range" value="A1:U3334"/>
        <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
        <parameter key="first_row_as_names" value="false"/>
        <list key="annotations">
          <parameter key="0" value="Name"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="date_format" value=""/>
        <parameter key="time_zone" value="SYSTEM"/>
        <parameter key="locale" value="English (United States)"/>
        <list key="data_set_meta_data_information">
          <parameter key="0" value="State.true.polynominal.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="1" value="Account Length.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="2" value="Area Code.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="3" value="Phone.true.polynominal.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="4" value="Int'l Plan.true.polynominal.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="5" value="VMail Plan.true.polynominal.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="6" value="VMail Message.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="7" value="Day Mins.true.numeric.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="8" value="Day Calls.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="9" value="Day Charge.true.real.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="10" value="Eve Mins.true.numeric.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="11" value="Eve Calls.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="12" value="Eve Charge.true.numeric.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="13" value="Night Mins.true.numeric.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="14" value="Night Calls.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="15" value="Night Charge.true.real.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="16" value="Intl Mins.true.numeric.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="17" value="Intl Calls.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="18" value="Intl Charge.true.numeric.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="19" value="CustServ Calls.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="20" value="Churn?.true.polynominal.attribute"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="read_not_matching_values_as_missings" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_array"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="179" y="30">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value=""/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="CustServ Calls|Day Calls|Intl Calls|Churn?"/>
        <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="value_type" value="attribute_value"/>
        <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/>
        <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/>
        <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/>
        <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="Set Role" width="90" x="179" y="120">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="Churn?"/>
        <parameter key="target_role" value="label"/>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="normalize" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" height="94" name="Normalize" width="90" x="179" y="210">
        <parameter key="return_preprocessing_model" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="create_view" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value=""/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="CustServ Calls|Day Calls|Intl Calls"/>
        <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="value_type" value="numeric"/>
        <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="except_value_type" value="real"/>
        <parameter key="block_type" value="value_series"/>
        <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_series_end"/>
        <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="method" value="range transformation"/>
        <parameter key="min" value="0.0"/>
        <parameter key="max" value="1.0"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="parallel_decision_tree" compatibility="6.5.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="gini index- no pruning Decision Tree" width="90" x="313" y="30">
        <parameter key="criterion" value="gini_index"/>
        <parameter key="maximal_depth" value="20"/>
        <parameter key="apply_pruning" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="confidence" value="0.25"/>
        <parameter key="apply_prepruning" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="minimal_gain" value="0.1"/>
        <parameter key="minimal_leaf_size" value="2"/>
        <parameter key="minimal_size_for_split" value="4"/>
        <parameter key="number_of_prepruning_alternatives" value="3"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="reporting:generate_report" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Generate Report" width="90" x="313" y="120">
        <parameter key="report_name" value="gini_index"/>
        <parameter key="format" value="HTML"/>
        <parameter key="report_to_repository" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="html_output_directory" value="C:\Users\RoshanaSheri\Desktop\dm"/>
        <parameter key="pdf_output_file" value="C:\Users\RoshanaSheri\Desktop\dm\gini_index.pdf"/>
        <parameter key="html_image_format" value="png"/>
        <parameter key="image_col_span" value="8"/>
        <parameter key="image_row_span" value="17"/>
        <parameter key="page_size" value="A4"/>
        <parameter key="page_format" value="portrait"/>
        <parameter key="template_type" value="none"/>
        <parameter key="image_alignment" value="aspect_ratio"/>
        <parameter key="set_background_color" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="background_color" value="255,255,255"/>
        <parameter key="page_width" value="595"/>
        <parameter key="page_height" value="842"/>
        <parameter key="top_page_margin" value="36"/>
        <parameter key="bottom_page_margin" value="36"/>
        <parameter key="left_page_margin" value="36"/>
        <parameter key="right_page_margin" value="36"/>
        <parameter key="section_one_font_size" value="12.0"/>
        <parameter key="section_one_font_style_bold" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_one_font_style_italic" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_one_font_style_underline" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_one_font_style_strikethrough" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_one_font_color" value="0,0,0"/>
        <parameter key="section_two_font_size" value="12.0"/>
        <parameter key="section_two_font_style_bold" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_two_font_style_italic" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_two_font_style_underline" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_two_font_style_strikethrough" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_two_font_color" value="0,0,0"/>
        <parameter key="section_three_font_size" value="12.0"/>
        <parameter key="section_three_font_style_bold" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_three_font_style_italic" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_three_font_style_underline" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_three_font_style_strikethrough" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_three_font_color" value="0,0,0"/>
        <parameter key="section_four_font_size" value="12.0"/>
        <parameter key="section_four_font_style_bold" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_four_font_style_italic" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_four_font_style_underline" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_four_font_style_strikethrough" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_four_font_color" value="0,0,0"/>
        <parameter key="section_five_font_size" value="12.0"/>
        <parameter key="section_five_font_style_bold" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_five_font_style_italic" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_five_font_style_underline" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_five_font_style_strikethrough" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="section_five_font_color" value="0,0,0"/>
        <parameter key="text_content_font_size" value="12.0"/>
        <parameter key="text_content_font_style_bold" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="text_content_font_style_italic" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="text_content_font_style_underline" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="text_content_font_style_strikethrough" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="text_content_font_color" value="0,0,0"/>
        <parameter key="system_fonts" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="directory_fonts" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="table_column_number" value="8"/>
        <parameter key="table_header_color" value="128,128,128"/>
        <parameter key="table_row_color_one" value="255,255,255"/>
        <parameter key="table_row_color_two" value="192,192,192"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="reporting:report" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Report" width="90" x="313" y="210">
        <parameter key="report_name" value="gini_index"/>
        <parameter key="specified" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="reportable_type" value=""/>
        <list key="parameters"/>
        <parameter key="image_width" value="1200"/>
        <parameter key="image_height" value="1200"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read Excel" from_port="output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Normalize" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Normalize" from_port="example set output" to_op="gini index- no pruning Decision Tree" to_port="training set"/>
      <connect from_op="gini index- no pruning Decision Tree" from_port="model" to_op="Generate Report" to_port="through 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Report" from_port="through 1" to_op="Report" to_port="reportable in"/>
      <connect from_op="Report" from_port="reportable out" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: It worked for me with the Iris data set. I replaced the first of your 4 operators with a retrieve of this from the sample repository. Perhaps if you try that to see if it works for you in your environment.

Comment: I think the problem is when the decision tree is so large. I want to get the graph without pruning the tree. Any ideas on how to capture the entire graph? I even tried to use the save image option in the results tab but it only saves the screen captured size of the image, not the whole graph.

Comment: Playing with the image sizes in the `Report` operator does create different sized PNG files and the image using the Iris data set does make it (although tiny and in the top right).

Comment: even though i changed the image size it doesn't work for my unpruned graph :(